# Send simple HTTP request with HTML submit button

Tags: javascript, html, http, dom

I have added a submit button to the `index.html` page that resides on my server side

```
<form method="get" action="/start">
    <h5>Start Ad-Placer!</h5>
    <input type="submit" value="Start">
</form>
```

I need the button to simply send a `http` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8484/get/start` to start some process. Then once the process is done after a few seconds, I need to simply display an alert message with the response message, acknowledging it is done.

How can I do that with minimum efforts (without using JQuery or other libraries).

Comment: Aren't you already doing it? Now just put `alert("something")` on the `start` page to alert the user

Comment: When you submit this form it sends a `GET` request to that URL. The URL should return an HTML page that includes the Javascript that displays the alert you want.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this without reloading the page? Then you need to use AJAX. There are many tutorials on the web.

Comment: @Barmar My server returns a piece of String message. I want to put it in the alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try something like this you can send a HTTP request and then alert a response. Just change https://google.com to your URL.

```
<h5>Start Ad-Placer!</h5>
<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="submit()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                alert(xhr.response);
            }
        }
        xhr.open('get', 'https://google.com', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.send();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `xhr.response` should be `xhr.responseText`?

Comment: Now it sends the request, but no response is shown. The alert is empty.

Comment: My response is a piece of text about OS: `OS: Linux 4.10.0-28-generic amd64
Processors (cores): 4`

Comment: It Depends on the `responseType` you either use response, responseText, responseXML. Try looking in the console at the XHR object to see what the status and response is.

Comment: @user3610275 Nice! This is what it says: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: This is a CORS issue, because you are making a request to a different domain. This requires adding the ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server side. here is a link for fixing CORS issues http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Comment: You could try changing the `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');` to `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');` that might work.

Comment: @user3610275 that change on `xhr` didn't work. Let me try server-side modification...

Comment: @user3610275 The server-side modification works! Had to set the access control `t.getResponseHeaders().set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this.

```
<form action="http://www.example.com" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="say">What greeting do you want to say?</label>
    <input name="say" id="say" value="Hi" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="to">Who do you want to say it to?</label>
    <input name="to" id="to" value="Mom" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Send my greetings</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data